# Multiple timestamp Snapshot duplicates in WAR file - why?

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, war

I have a multi-module Project Bookstore (one of the modules is a WAR). Some modules depend on projectX(and some of the dependencies depend on that projectX too). I've used maven properties and dependency management across the modules to ensure they everything depends on the same version (0.0.7-SNAPSHOT). See the dependency-analyze in [1]

Having performed a lot of changes in projectX and a few others, my repositories have a lot of timestamped snapshots of projectX.

When I ran my CI server's deployment job (golas "deploy site:site" followed by "site:deploy") I get a WAR file with multiple timestamped versions of the projectX's SNAPSHOT (3 timestamped of each module - api,core,mail - to be exact, 9 in total).

Running the goal package locally doesn't yield the same problem - only one snapshot per module is packaged in the war, as expected.

Does anyone have an idea why maven is packaging more than one Snapshot. Since they are all

Cheers,

Miguel Almeida

[1]

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:analyze (default-cli) @ bookstore-persist ---
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.clinicalmanagement:clinicaltrial-api:jar:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.security:security-api:jar:0.0.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.struts.xwork:xwork-core:jar:2.3.4:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.audit:audit-core:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.security:security-core:jar:0.0.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.security:security-mail:jar:0.0.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.0:compile
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.company:projectX-shared:pom:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.company:projectX-model:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.company:projectX-configuration:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:test
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.8:runtime
[WARNING]    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.8:runtime
[WARNING]    org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.8:runtime
[WARNING]    log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:runtime
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.2:provided
[WARNING]    postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.0-801.jdbc4:provided
[WARNING]    javassist:javassist:jar:3.4.GA:compile
[WARNING]    javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:provided
[WARNING]    cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.security:security:pom:0.0.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.audit:audit:pom:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]                                                                        
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Bookstore Web 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:analyze (default-cli) @ projectX-web >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.0:create (default) @ projectX-web ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:analyze (default-cli) @ projectX-web ---
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.company.clinicalmanagement:clinicaltrial-api:jar:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.security:security-api:jar:0.0.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.3.Final:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.struts.xwork:xwork-core:jar:2.3.4:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.security:security-core:jar:0.0.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.audit:audit-struts:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.audit:audit-core:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.security:security-mail:jar:0.0.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.apache.commons:commons-jci-fam:jar:1.0:compile
[WARNING]    postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.0-801.jdbc4:test
[WARNING]    org.apache.struts:struts2-sitemesh-plugin:jar:2.3.4:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.struts:struts2-config-browser-plugin:jar:2.3.4:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.struts:struts2-spring-plugin:jar:2.3.4:compile
[WARNING]    commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.1.1:compile
[WARNING]    org.company:projectX-model:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.company:projectX-persist:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.audit:audit:pom:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.8:runtime
[WARNING]    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.8:runtime
[WARNING]    org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.8:runtime
[WARNING]    log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:runtime
[WARNING]    c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.2:test
[WARNING]    org.company:projectX-configuration:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.company:projectX-configuration:test-jar:tests:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.security:security:pom:0.0.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.xhtmlrenderer:core-renderer:jar:R8-final:compile
[WARNING]    com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.7:compile
[WARNING]    com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery:struts2-jquery-plugin:jar:3.0.1:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.application.version:application-version:jar:0.0.2:compile
[INFO]                                                                        
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building bookstore-acceptance 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] <<< maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:analyze (default-cli) @ bookstore-acceptance <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:analyze (default-cli) @ bookstore-acceptance ---
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.clinicalmanagement:clinicaltrial-api:jar:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.audit:audit-struts:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.struts:struts2-junit-plugin:jar:2.3.4:test
[WARNING]    org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.3.Final:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.security:security-api:jar:0.0.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.easymock:easymock:jar:3.0:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.systemDate:systemDate:jar:0.0.2:compile
[WARNING]    com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7:compile
[WARNING]    junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.struts.xwork:xwork-core:jar:2.3.4:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.clinicalmanagement:clinicaltrial-core:jar:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.audit:audit-core:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    info.cukes:cucumber-core:jar:1.0.9:test
[WARNING]    org.company.security:security-core:jar:0.0.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.company.security:security-mail:jar:0.0.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    info.cukes:cucumber-java:jar:1.0.9:test
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    info.cukes:cucumber-spring:jar:1.0.9:test
[WARNING]    postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.0-801.jdbc4:provided
[WARNING]    org.company:projectX-persist:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.company:projectX-persist:test-jar:tests:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:test
[WARNING]    org.company:projectX-configuration:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    org.company:projectX-configuration:test-jar:tests:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[WARNING]    c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.2:test
[WARNING]    org.company:projectX-web:jar:classes:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:test
[WARNING]    org.company:projectX-web:test-jar:tests:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:test
[WARNING]    org.apache.struts:struts2-spring-plugin:jar:2.3.4:compile
[WARNING]    javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:provided
[WARNING]    javax.servlet:jsp-api:jar:2.0:provided
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with the maven-war-plugin.  I was able to resolve this by upgrading to version 2.4 of the plugin.  Here's the relevant jira: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MWAR-296?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=318472#comment-318472

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do `clean deploy site:site`, otherwise the previous snapshots will still be hanging around in the target directory of the build.